# android: parse object with null values

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have a query that retrieves a parse objects:
i tried to debug the callback function, and i found that i am getting a correct number of objects but all of their values are null.
allthough there is a value called "state" in which i am getting the values
what am i doing wrong? how do i get the values properly?

```
  final List<Kehila> newKehilas = new ArrayList<>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Kehila");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e("UNITE", e.toString());
            } else {

                for (ParseObject k : list) {

                    Kehila newKehila = new Kehila();
                    newKehila.setObjectId(k.getString("objectId"));
                    newKehila.setName(k.getString("name"));
                    newKehila.setCity(k.getString("city"));
                    newKehila.setNeighborhood(k.getString("neighborhood"));
                    newKehila.setStreet(k.getString("street"));
                    newKehila.setHouseNumber(k.getInt("houseNumber"));

                    newKehilas.add(newKehila);
                }
            }

        }
    });
   return newKehilas;
```

Comment: This code adding elements to the list runs asynchronously, so the return statement at the end will likely return an empty list

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `save()` or `saveEventually()` on your new objects.

Comment: their are objects in dashboard.., it crashes whenever i try to access one of the values by getX...